# How to deliver properties files in addition to artifacts?

Tags: maven-2, build-process, build-automation

I am using **Maven2** to build a WAR project.
Some properties files are dependent on the environment targeted for a release.

I want to deliver, in addition of the WAR, a file called `datasource.xml`. This file already exists in my project directory, but contains properties that will be filtered during the build (i.e. some `${foo.bar}`).

In others words, after running the command **mvn clean install**, I want to see in my `target/` directory two files, `my-webapp.war` and `datasource.xml`.

Note that `datasource.xml` **must not** be included in the `my-webapp.war` artifact!

How can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can attach additional artifacts using the [build-helper-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/attach-artifact-mojo.html). The configuration below would attach datasource.xml as an additional artifact during the *package* phase. If that artifact is defined outside of src/main/resources and src/main/webapp it will not be included in the war.

Update: to ensure resource filtering is applied per your comment, you can specify an execution of the [resource-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html)'s copy-resources goal, specifying filtering to be applied. You can then still attach that filtered artifact using the build-helper-maven-plugin by referencing the corresponding target directory. I've updated the example below to show this usage.

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>copy-resources</id>
      <phase>validate</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/datasource</outputDirectory>
        <resources>          
          <resource>
            <directory>src/main/datasource</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
          </resource>
        </resources>              
      </configuration>            
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.3</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>attach-artifacts</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <artifacts>
          <artifact>
            <file>${project.build.outputDirectory}/datasource/datasource.xml</file>
            <type>xml </type>
            <classifier>datasource</classifier>
          </artifact>
        </artifacts>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

This won't appear in the target folder, but it will be deployed/installed to the repository alongside the war.

The attached artifact can be referenced by defining a dependency with the classifier "datasource". For example:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-artifact-id/artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <classifier>datasource</classifier>
  <type>xml</type>
</dependency>
```

You could use the the dependency plugin's [copy goal](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-artifacts.html) to retrieve the artifact and put it wherever it is required as part of your deployment process.

Comment: This is not exaclty what I am looking for (I only need the datasource.xml to be located in the target/ dir, not installed in the repository), but this solution is quite interesting however.

Comment: This solution does not fit my need also because the XML file copied in the repository is *not* filtered (i.e. I still have ${foo.bar} in it).

Comment: so to be clear, you want resource filtering to be applied, but the artifact to not be included in the war?

Comment: maven-resources-plugin will filter the output. you might want to check that the filter is defined under build and not under the war-plugin. filters defined under the war-plugin will only be applied to web-resources.