# Maven shipping scripts

Tags: maven, maven-3

I am completely new to Maven and come from an ant world. I am having lots of trouble something that might be really trivial.

I want to have a maven project that is made out of non-code items that I want to ship along my jars. These items are DDL scripts, installer scripts a couple of utility scripts, readmes etc.

I do not want to use "resources" in the corresponding java projects since I do not want them living in the actual product jars. I want them shipped as separate artifacts that just like any other jar.

It is acceptable to bundle them up in a jar or zip, etc.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [build helper](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/) plug-in to add additional artifacts to the Maven module.

Check out the answer to the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345906/how-to-deliver-properties-files-in-addition-to-artifacts)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found it and it was pretty simple. Just created a project added a simple pom with no plugin pacakging jar and I create the proper dir structure
src/main/resources/...

This builds it into a jar